# Is it useful for runners to cross-train using kettlebells?

Tags: running, fat-loss, kettlebell

I'm using running to help burn some fat mostly because it is the only cardio I really enjoy doing.  I know muscle helps burn fat faster.  Would using a kettlebell between runs help promote fat loss, lean up, and get my pace higher on my runs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you mean kettlebells. [Kettlebell swings](http://www.crossfit.com/journal/library/25_04_kettlebell_swing.pdf) are a great full body exercise that involves explosive extending of the hips. Strengthening this group of muscles (the posterior chain) is important for [running](http://training.fitness.com/running-cycling/posterior-chain-work-runners-42325.html).

Answer (score 1):

Any proper weight training program will help 'toning up' and weight loss.  For a better run time a lot is dependent on the type of run (long/short distance) and what is holding you back from improving through running itself.  To be a better runner, you have to run - you might consider doing sprints (Tabata protocol or any that fit your needs) for endurance or plyometric training for improved explosive power.  A good overall weight program will help build strength and endurance throughout your body potentially reducing lack of endurance or power by building up supporting muscle groups.